# how to create wmts service with openlayer version 4 with mapproxy

Tags: openlayers

I published my map with geoserver and i used mapproxy for wmts service.
mapproxy have got sample with openlayer version 2 and I want use openlayer version 4 but didn't work that version 4.

this is mapproxy sample with openlayer2

```
var map;
var mapOptions = {
projection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:3857'),
resolutions: [156543.03392804097, 78271.51696402048, 39135.75848201024,
19567.87924100512, 9783.93962050256, 4891.96981025128, 2445.98490512564, 
1222.99245256282,
611.49622628141, 305.748113140705, 152.8740565703525, 76.43702828517625,
38.21851414258813, 19.109257071294063, 9.554628535647032, 4.777314267823516,
2.388657133911758, 1.194328566955879, 0.5971642834779395, 
0.29858214173896974],
units: 'm',
maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.342789244, -20037508.342789244,
20037508.342789244, 20037508.342789244),
tileSize: new OpenLayers.Size(256, 256)
};

map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', mapOptions);

var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMTS({
 name: "WMTS osm",
 url: '../wmts/osm/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileCol}/{TileRow}.png',
 layer: 'osm',
 matrixSet: 'webmercator',
 format: 'png',
 isBaseLayer: true,
 style: 'default',
 requestEncoding: 'REST'
});

map.addLayer(layer)
```

this is my sample code with openlayer version 4 and dosen't work with this version

```
function createWMTS() {
    var gridsetName = 'EPSG:900913';

    var wmtslayer = new ol.source.WMTS({
        url: 
        layer: 'osm',
        matrixSet: 'webmercator',
        isBaseLayer: true,
        format: 'image/png',
             style: 'default',
        requestEncoding: 'REST',
        projection: new ol.proj.Projection({
            code: 'EPSG:3857',
            units: 'm',
            axisOrientation: 'neu'
        }),
        tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
            tileSize: [256, 256],
            extent: [-2.003750834E7, -2.003750834E7, 2.003750834E7, 2.003750834E7],
            resolutions: resolutions,
            matrixIds: params['TILEMATRIX']
        }),
        style: "",
        wrapX: true
    })

    return wmtslayer;
};
   var view = new ol.View({
    center: [5720657.8367, 4263876.019],
    zoom: 5 ,
     minZoom: 3,
        maxZoom: 19
});
  var gitaBaseMap = createWMTS();
  var rasterLayer = new ol.layer.Tile();
 rasterLayer.setSource(gitaBaseMap);
 var format = 'image/png';
 map = new ol.Map({
     layers: [rasterLayer],
     target: 'map',
     view: view,});
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did for Open Layers 6;

I also used Proj4 to transform the OSM basemap.

*Tip:*

I get `center` and `resolution` parameters of `ol.View` via following console commands;

`map.getView().getResolution()` and `map.getView().getCenter()`

You can call these commands in browser's console while you're viewing map.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      html,
      body,
      #map {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.6.2/proj4-src.min.js"></script>
    <title>OpenLayers example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var resolutions = [264.5833333333, 132.2919312505292, 66.1459656252646, 33.0729828126323,
    16.53649140631615, 8.268245703158074, 4.134122851579037, 2.0670614257895186,
    1.0335307128947593];
        proj4.defs('EPSG:27700', '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 ' +
    '+x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy ' +
    '+towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 ' +
    '+units=m +no_defs');
     ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);
      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
              source: new ol.source.OSM()
            }),
            new ol.layer.Tile({
              source: new ol.source.WMTS({
                url: '[mapproxy_url]/wmts/moata/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileCol}/{TileRow}.png',
                layer: 'moata',
                format: 'image/png',
                matrixSet: 'mercator',
                requestEncoding: 'REST',
                projection: ol.proj.get('EPSG:27700'),
                tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
                  resolutions: [264.5833333333, 132.2919312505292, 66.1459656252646, 33.0729828126323,
    16.53649140631615, 8.268245703158074, 4.134122851579037, 2.0670614257895186,
    1.0335307128947593],
                    extent: [258536.05215197292,446521.1903102073,421600.6383919524,586398.6826073326],
                    origin: [-5220400.0, 4470200.0],
                    tileSize: 512,
                    matrixIds:["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
                })
              })
            })
        ],      
        view: new ol.View({
            center: [343273.8405364175, 526209.345032014],
            projection: ol.proj.get('EPSG:27700'),
            resolution: 82.71791209587954
        }),
        target: 'map'
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```